# Finding values using Where clause on corresponding columns ( MYSQL )

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to query this sql statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE value1 IN (column1) 
AND value2 IN (column2) 
AND value3 IN (column3)...
```

So in this query the `WHERE` clause is finding the value1 in column1 and value2 in column2 and so forth

this although works perfectly...

but my problem is this, is there a better way to write this code something similar like The Insert query statement below.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) 
                VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

u can see that the values correspond with the columns

could a similar statement be written like this

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM `tablename` 
    WHERE  VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...); 
    IN (column1 AND column2 AND column3 AND ...)
```

Comment: Please see the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help add clarity.

Comment: I took sometime editing and explaining it better could u plz take some time out to look at it if it make better sense now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you even thought of the operator `IN`.

Your query should be written like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE column1 = value1
  AND column2 = value2
  AND column3 = value3 ...
```

Another way to apply the same logic is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE (column1, column2, column3, ...) = (value1, value2, value3, ...)
```

Comment: thanks that helped alot... one more question what if some of the values i am generating are empty strings is it still possible to run the query?

SELECT * 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE (column1, column2, column3, ...) = (value1, " ", value3, ...)

somthing like this ?

Comment: @SulemanMughal an empty string is `''` without any spaces. The query checks for exact equality. All columns must be equal to their corresponding values. It works for any non-null values. If there are nulls, you can use `<=>` instead of `=`.

Comment: i have another question regarding the syntax of a sql command 
`UPDATE table_name SET (column1, column2, column3)=(value1, value2, value3) WHERE id = value`
could this command run in mysql

Comment: @SulemanMughal no, this syntax is not supported by MySql.

Comment: then is there be any friendly alternative to the traditional method ?

Comment: @SulemanMughal no, only the standard syntax: `UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1, column2=value2, column3=value3 WHERE id = value`